# Box2d SetMassFromShape replaced with SetMassData

Tags: box2d

I'm trying to get some fluid code working and found that it was written using an older version of Box2D.
I've been trying to make the changes myself but found that I got stuck in this part.

```
b2PolygonDef polyDef;
polyDef.SetAsBox(b2Random(0.3f,0.7f), b2Random(0.3f,0.7f));

polyDef.density = 3.0f;
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.position = b2Vec2(0.0f,25.0f);

bodyDef.angularDamping = 0.5f;

bod = m_world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
bod->CreateShape(&polyDef);
bod->SetMassFromShapes();
```

SetMassFromShapes has been replaced with SetMassData(<#const b2MassData *data#>);

My question is. What data should I give it having a look at the posted code using an older Box2D?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

SetMassFromShapes was replaced by ResetMassData in [r13](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/detail?r=13&path=/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.h) and [r25](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/detail?r=25&path=/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.h) revisions. Although, you don't need call it, because it calls automaticly. Look at r13 description:

> Removed b2Body::SetMassFromShapes. Now the mass is automatically updated when
>   you call b2Body::CreateFixture/DestroyFixture. This was done to make the API
>   simpler.

Comment: What about GetNormals(). That one seems to have been removed as well. How does it work now ?

Comment: I know, that there is public attribute in b2PolygonShape m_normals. Looks like, it is what you need.